# Increment and ternary operator precedence in c++

Tags: c++, iterator, operator-precedence

I would like to print elements of a vector separated by semicolon.
The following code snippet produces a strange result: the result starts with the second element of the vector. Can anybody write an explanation? When is the iterator incremented in this case?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    vector<int> v(10);
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) {
        v[i] = i;
    }

    for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); )
        std::cout << *it << ( (++it != v.end() ) ? ";" : "" );
}
```

Comment: this should work on gcc 7 which implements the C++17 standard

Comment: That will be great. Unfortunately I cannot influence our infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to C++17, the order in which *it and ++it are carried is unspecified. See, e.g., https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

This can be seen in an easier example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 3;
    std::cout << i << ++i;
}
```

where my compiler (Apple LLVM with `-Wall` option) reports

```
warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]
    std::cout << i << ++i;
                 ~    ^
```

Comment: If you read the link you gave, you'll see that the sequence is *unspecified*, which is not (in the C++ standard) the same as undefined.       Also, in this case, things changed in C++17 :  in an expression like `cout << x << y` it is guaranteed that `x` will, since C++17, be evaluated before `y`

Comment: @Peter: You are right, I meant *unspecified* but did not know about the C++17 change.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. By the way gcc says the following warning:
*warning: operation on 'i' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]*

Comment: Pre-17 It could very well be undefined if the vector iterator is a typedef for a pointer. And is (pre-17) undefined in your example with int i

Answer (score 3):

[Generally](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> Order of evaluation of the operands of almost all C++ operators (including the order of evaluation of function arguments in a function-call expression and the order of evaluation of the subexpressions within any expression) is unspecified.

Since C++17 there is a special rule for shifts:

> In a shift operator expression `E1<<E2` and `E1>>E2`, every value computation and side-effect of `E1` is sequenced before every value computation and side effect of `E2`.